# Retrieving a boolean value in a function using php

Tags: php, function, return, boolean

```
   function sample($number){
    if ($number % 2 == 0){
    echo "Even";
    }else{
    echo "Odd";
    }

    sample(3);
```

When I replace echo with return nothing happens? How do you know if it returns something? 
The below sample is what concerns me. Thanks in advance!

```
 function sample($number){
    if ($number % 2 == 0){
    return true;
    }else{
    return false;
    }

sample(3);
```

Comment: when you **return** something you need something to **assign** the returned value. In your second case, you should **assign** the sample function result to a **variable**, like: `$result = sample(3);` and then echo it: `echo $result;` or just echo the result: `echo sample(3);`.

Comment: do I need to assign a variable when it returns a boolean value?

Comment: If you want to use the returned value later, then yes. If you don't care about the result, you don't need to.

Comment: Not necessarely. If you return false, the result of the function will be false. If you don't assign that result (returned by sample(3)) to a variable or don't echo it nothing terrible will happen, but you can't expect PHP to know what you want to do with it (for example, **echoing it**). If you're used to other languages, you're treating a **boolean** function exactly like a **void** one. No one will kill you in php, but if you **return** something then it's probably because you want to **use it**, hence you **assign the result to a variable**, else you just use a blank return: `return;`.

Comment: Thanks -briosheje it works!

Answer (score 1):

Something definetly happens. You just aren't catching the result.

```
// Return true or false at random
function trueOrFalse()
{
    return (rand(1, 10) > 5) ? true : false;
}

// Now we are going to check what is being returned
print_r(trueOrFalse()); // true
print_r(trueOrFalse()); // false
print_r(trueOrFalse()); // false
print_r(trueOrFalse()); // true
```

You can also use the return value in if statements and such:

```
if (trueOrFalse() == true) {
    echo "It was true this time";
}
```

The PHP Manual tells us

> Values are returned by using the optional return statement. Any type may be returned, including arrays and objects. This causes the function to end its execution immediately and pass control back to the line from which it was called. See return for more information.

#### Additional reading

- [PHP Manual on return values](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php)

Comment: I hope that `return` statement is just for illustrative purposes?! That should be just `return rand(1, 10) > 5;`. No redundant ternary operation necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sample(3)) echo 'This is even';
else echo 'this is odd';
```

Manual and read about functions, returns, IF

Answer (score 0):

When you return a boolean, it is either true or false. If you really want to output a boolean, you can try with [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.var-dump.php) :

```
var_dump(true);
```

will output  **yourfile.php:3:boolean true**

and

```
var_dump(false);
```

will output **yourfile.php:3:boolean false**

Booleans are not made to be outputed but to check if a statement is true or false.

In your case, you want to know if a number is even, so the method could be named isEven and return true if the number is even.

Then you could use it like :

```
<tr class="<?= isEven($i) ? 'even' : 'odd' ?>">
```

Or

```
if (isEven($i)) {
    ...
}
```